# Cancel button login screen Facebook HTTP request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview, facebook-login

I've got an IOS app that only contains a webview. Users have a choice whether they log in with a account on the website or with their Facebook account.

The Facebook login is going with a HTTP request directly to the oauth of Facebook. If users are logging in it's not a big deal and everything is working fine. But when users push the Facebook login button while they don't want to login with Facebook, they aren't able to go back to the previous page.

Of course Android has the same problem. But an Android phone has the possibility to push the back button.

I'm using a HTTP request because the server where the website is on have some limitations. Is there somebody with the same problem or somebody that has a soluition for this?

Comment: Nobody has a solution for this problem?